# Red Hat 5.10 fail to boot on HP DL380 G7

Tags: redhat, hp, boot, hp-proliant

I'm trying to install Red Hat 5.10 x86_64 on an HP DL380 G7 server, everything goes fine and I get the successful installation message but don't know why the server fails to boot!

I've done the installation many times with different partitioning layouts and even the default anaconda partitioning...

Any help is appreciated

Comment: what dmesg shows on the boot? And at what stage it gets stuck?

Comment: It doesn't boot! and machine tries to read from other media like CD...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set the Boot Controller option in the RAID controller's BIOS.

As the server begins its POST process and the devices are initializing, press `F8` to enter the Smart Array P410 RAID controller's BIOS configuration.

Once in, set the boot volume so the system know which device to boot from. It *is* possible to install an OS without this setting configured and have the problem you're experiencing.

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm :)