# HP DL360 Gen9: Smart Storage Administrator hangs loading config from P440ar; BIOS sees P440ar controller, but no disks

Tags: hp-proliant, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

I have been scanning the entire web (or so) for possible similar cases, but to no avail.
Situation:

- DL360 Gen9, BIOS version P89 v2.92 (2021)
- P440ar installed, firmware 7.20
- the (F9) System Configuration utilities see this PCI-device (the P440ar) as "enabled"
- the ILO4 sees all the installed physical disks in the P440ar, and the configured logical 'arrays' with those physical disks
- booting is set to be in UEFI mode
- booting from Linux (Ubuntu) install USB works, disks are seen, installation goes fine
- booting from the installed disk fails, no bootable devices found
- going via Intelligent Provisioning into the Storage Administrator hangs on the "Loading" page (loading the config from the array, I assume)
- the BIOS boot order page shows nothing of the P440ar, only NICs

Why is this P440ar not seen correctly by the BIOS ?
Why is the Storage Administrator hanging on this "Loading" page ?

Comment: open up a ticket on the vendor as per usually an business Administrator would do. Did you already done this?

Comment: What are the make/model of disks in the system?

Comment: @ewwhite : these are standard HP disks 2.4TB and 600GB ; none of them are visible from the BIOS, but they are perfectly visible (the Logical Devices made from them in the P440ar, that is) from the Ubuntu installer.

Comment: @djdomi: no, we have no support for this server with HP; it's my private infrastructure, I purchased it 2nd hand

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance you're running into a SCSI enumeration issue?

You mentioned installing Ubuntu via USB. Based on that, which device was the bootloader written to?

In general, I install operating systems via the ILO and an installation ISO.

Would you be willing to try that?

Comment: The Ubuntu installer wrote it to the Logical Device which is presented by the P440ar controller, one that was created before as a single-disk 'RAID-0 array' from the first 600GB (very first HDD SAS slot)

Comment: I install Ubuntu exactly this same way on a multitude of Gen8 servers, never had any issue with them. I got this Gen9 server now, and try the same method, but I guess it is a firmware, or BIOS/UEFI thing or so. The ILO4 perfectly reads the config from the P440ar, the Ubuntu installer perfectly sees the Logical Devices, but the BIOS doesn't see any of those configs, nor is  the Storage Administrator tool (launched from the BIOS startup) able to read the config of the controller

Comment: While this process worked on Gen8 servers, that doesn't mean that it will on Gen9 systems.

Comment: you are right that one system does no necessarily behave the same as another make, but in this case HP is fairly consistent, luckily; I have built numerous Gen9 and Gen10 servers with exactly the same method.
Boot, go info Storage Administrator (F10), configure logical devices from the disks in the SAS controller, then reboot from USB on which the Ubuntu installer is loaded. Installing correctly Ubuntu, reboot from those disks, and done.

Comment: Furthermore, the issue is not about installing Ubuntu or any other software on the disks; the issue starts already with the Storage Administrator no longer being able to read the configuration from the P440ar. On the other hand, the ILO4 web access gives a perfect view of this configuration from the P440ar.
Is the ILO4 caching this info maybe, so that it does not effectively reads the P440ar config each time this is requested in the ILO4 browser pages ?

Comment: You're missing or denying the chance that there's something wrong with this hardware. If all experience and history point to this process working, and THIS server is the anomaly... What does that tell you about this particular system?

Comment: hi @ewwhite, clearly I try to deny that the hardware would be the cause, because then I have no way to get it repaired without substantial costs. So I hope to find that there is a software cause in the IP or SSA, cos that is something that I can fix myself. I found some other posts on the web where re-installing the IP resolved similar situations, so I am going to try this last option.

Comment: Still I would like to understand why the ILO4 can present the entire config of logical devices on the P440ar, whereas the BIOS doesn't find any disk in the controller. If the controller is faulty, then ILO4 would also not be able to display any of its configs, correct?

Comment: Re-installing the Intelligent Provisioning (v2.87) fixed the hanging Smart Storage Administrator.
In SSA, I can see again all the configured logical devices on the P440ar.
So no hardware error with the cards, or the P440ar, I guess.
Will reboot again and concentrate on why the BIOS is not showing any disk from the P440ar as device from which I can (attempt to) boot...

Comment: In the SSA, select the P440ar, go into Config, and choose the option "set bootable drives/volumes" ...
None was set to be a bootable drive.
So I set my (logical) drive on which the Ubuntu was installed from the USB, as primary boot device.
Reboot into BIOS, the "Boot Order" now finally shows this drive !
Proceed with the boot, and off we go straight into the Ubuntu.

Case closed. No hardware issue, but SSA config incomplete.
Thx all for your time and suggestions !

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we don't know the provenance of this system, and there are additional considerations for using old/preowned hardware.

- Run a BIOS reset to system shipping defaults. This is the first thing you should do with any repurposed/old server like this
- Upgrade your Intelligent Provisioning on this server (*Look for "HPE Intelligent Provisioning Recovery Media" for Gen9 systems*)
- Upgrade the ILO4 firmware of this system

Comment: thx again for your time to reply on my issue;
I did all of these resets/upgraded, but this problem persists. No further upgrades can be done AFAIK.

Comment: The weird thing is that initially I was able to configure the P440ar array via the Storage Administration utility (started from the boot); this is the configuration that I still see from the ILO4.
This configuration was usable for the Ubuntu installer, which completed successfully all the way to the end of the installation.
However during the (UEFI) boot process, the BIOS does not see any disk from the array (bootable or not, regardless).

Comment: So I cleared the NVRAM, and tried to upgrade with SSP, but this failed. Someone suggested to then remove the P440ar first, and now the upgrade with SSP went fine.
But, BIOS still did not see any disk from the P440ar. Moreover, now the problem when Storage Administration starts (startup hangs on the "Loading..." message, P440ar not responding, sort of)

In ILO4 I can still the config of the P440ar : is this information retrieved by ILO4 from P440ar during each reboot? If so, why would Storage Administration not be able to retrieve the same?. If not, then where is this information cached ?

Comment: _"We don't know the provenance of this system"_ - I think that still applies. There's a point where this shouldn't be so difficult. It indicates that there's a problem with your hardware. If you've downloaded the SPP DVD image, please use that to open the Smart Storage Administrator instead of the Intelligent Provisioning version. Also make sure to [select your boot drive in the Array configuration](https://serverfault.com/a/548835/13325).

Answer (score -1):

In the SSA, select the P440ar, go into Config, and choose the option "set bootable drives/volumes" .